# Finding Noun-Verb combinations with POS-tagging in a sentence

Tags: python, nlp, feature-extraction, pos-tagger

i want to extract some features from a text with pos-tagging. My aim is it to retrieve Noun-Verb combinations in a list. For the POS-tagging i used Spacy.
Now my code looks like this:

```
from spacy.de import German
nlp = German() 
Verb = ["VERB"]  
NN = ["NOUN"]

sentence = [["Du musst folgendes tun: Scheibe schließen, Tuer oeffnen, Fenster", ["Das ist deine Loesung: Sitz zurückstellen"])

texts = somePreprocessing(sentence) #Tokenization, Stopword removal

list2 = []
verb_toks = []
noun_toks = []
verblist = []
nounlist = []
pairlist = []

for text in texts:
    for s in text:
         st = nlp(unicode(s))
         list.append(st)
         for word in st:
            if word.pos_ in Verb:
                verblist.append(word)
            if word.pos_ in NN:
                nounlist.append(word)
        if len(verblist) != 0 and len(nounlist) != 0:
        pairlist.append((verblist, nounlist))
        verblist = []
        nounlist = []

    list2.append(list)
    list = []
print verblist
print nounlist
print pairlist
```

The output should look like this: [["Scheibe", "schließen, "Tuer", "oeffnen", "Fenster", "anheben"], ["Sitz", "zurückstellen"]]

**To sum it up:**
Given a list of sentences such as [["This is a example sentence"],["This is another example sentence"]].
My aim is it to retrieve a list like this [["Noun", "Verb, "Noun", "Verb, "Noun", "Verb], ["Noun", "Verb]]) based on POS-tagging.

```
listOfSentence = [[".."],[".."]]
pos = posTagger(listOfSentences)
list = matchingNounVerb(pos)
print list
=> [["Noun", "Verb, "...", "..., "...", "...], ["Noun", "Verb]])
```

Thank you for your help ;)